# Grab Jquery Selector value into php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a variable in jquery selector and i want to grab it using php.

Say `$('‪#‎rowidtext‬').val(id);` and can pass to `<input type="text" name="rowidtex" id="rowidtext" >` but i want to receive in something like `$value=??`

How can it be achieved?

The code in js are:
function viewrow(id){
    $('#rowidtext').val(id);

$( "#viewrecordsdialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
    }

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#viewrecordsdialog" ).dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                     },
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons: [

            {
                text: "Close",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }

        ]
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a hidden form which will be submitted when reloading the page, and then grab the result via PHP.

Comment: I dont want to submit, I just want to receive and filter my other queries

Answer (score 0):

Create another  named anyDivName

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxLoaded(response) {
        $('#anyDivName').empty().html(response);
    }
    function doRequest() {
        var rowId= $('#rowidtext‬').val();
        $('#anyDivName').empty().html('loading');
        $.ajax({
            url : "results.php",
            type : 'POST',
            success : ajaxLoaded,
            data : {
                val : rowId
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then get that variable with:

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['val'] )) {
            $intCase = intval ( $_POST ['val'] );
        } else {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Tried but still dont receiving it.